# How to copy multi files to a specific directory/location inside a Docker container

Tags: docker

I have five files: config.php, login.php, logout.php, register.php, welcome.php and I want to copy them to /var/www/html by using 1 layer

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache
COPY ./welcome.php, config.php  /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create directory let's say `mydirectory` and add all your `.php` files there

so your dockerfile should be like this

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache
COPY mydirectory/ /var/www/html/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Comment: Yes thank you.  when I ran the last dockerfile I got the following error:  When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /

Comment: Btw, how to run Healthcheck in this kind of Dockerfile. I need to curl port 80, right?

Comment: yes do curl localhost:<portnumber> from exec mode of container

Comment: HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost:80/ping || exit 1   ----->  Doesn't work with my dockerfile.

Comment: check ```ping localhost:8080```

Comment: or ```wget -qO- localhost:8080```

Comment: So the commant should be--->   HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s \ CMD wget -qO- localhost:8080/ping  ?

Comment: HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=5s --retries=3 CMD wget localhost:8080/healthz -q -O - > /dev/null 2>&1   ???? This one?

Comment: @yoram have you added this to your dockerfile ```HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/ || exit 1``` just above your CMD instruction?

Comment: after adding above command to dockerfile then build the image and run the image and the do this to check the health check ```docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health}}' <containerid>```

Comment: and make sure you add curl to your docker image as health check is using curl so check I have updated my answer I have added curl

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts, Dashrath Mundkar, thank you!!!!!!!!